# Where can I find beginner's information about quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Popular books on QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11287/popular-books-on-qm)

I hope that this question is suitable for this site.

I am interested in reading up on quantum theory so that I can reasonably understand the concepts of a Copenhagen vs. Bohm interpretation of quantum mechanics.

I'm interested in quantum theory in general but have absolutely no experience with it. I don't care about the math, but I do want to hear the concepts, how they were "discovered", what they explain about the universe, and why they are considered true.

What is a book or set of books that would help me go from not understanding it at all to having some kind of intuition? Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: While it's not really a bad question, we keep a tight lid on book recommendations and this is just too close to the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting book explaining the essence of quantum mechanics in a way that requires a minimal mathematical background (just knowing some linear algebra could help, but the book actually explains the necessary math) is [David Albert's Quantum Mechanics and Experience](http://www.ebook3000.com/Quantum-Mechanics-and-Experience_50973.html). It tackles the main interpretations of quantum mechanics: the Copenhagen interpretation, the Bohmian interpretation as well as Many World and Many Minds.